# Equality of Integrands Involving Dirac Delta Functions

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

Say, I have the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x-y) \, dx 
= f(y) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x-y) \, dx = f(y).$$

Again consider the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y) \delta(x-y) \, dx 
= f(y) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x-y) \, dx = f(y).$$

**My Question**

In this case, is $$f(x) \delta(x-y) = f(y) \delta(x-y) \, ?$$

The reason I am hesitating to conclude that (using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus) is $f(x) \delta(x-y)$ not being a function (strictly speaking) due to the presence of the Dirac delta 'function'. For more details, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2342354/97129).

Although, it is quite common in Physics, for instance, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/607029/how-to-compute-normalization-of-one-particle-states-for-klein-gordon-field-quant?rq=1#607029) in the normalization of one-particle states.

Comment: Why can $f(y)$ go out of integral, at first case?

Comment: In the first case, $f(x)$ is assumed to be some ordinary function. The product $f(x) \delta(x-y)$ is zero everywhere except at $x = y$. It follows that $f(x) \delta(x-y) = f(y) \delta(x-y)$. The integration is wrt $x$ and hence $f(y)$ is pulled out of the integration being a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As you say, both of them are equal to $f(x)\delta(0)$ when $x=y,$ while they are equal to $0$ when $x\neq y.$

I think maybe the point you're confused about is how to define "equal" for non-ordinary functions, and how to understand "multiply" for non-ordinary functions like $f(x)\delta(x-y)$. You can see [generalized function](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) for help.

In brief, $\delta(x)$ can be seen as a functional on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),$ which acts as
$$\langle \delta(x), h(x)\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\delta(x) h(x)dx=h(0),\quad \forall h\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n),$$
so for given $y$, $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle f(x)\delta(x-y),h(x)\rangle &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\delta(x-y) h(x)dx=f(y)h(y)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(y)\delta(x-y)h(x)dx=\langle f(y)\delta(x-y),h(x)\rangle
\end{aligned}$$
Thus regarded as functional on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R^n_x})$, for any give $y,$ $f(x)\delta(x-y)=f(y)\delta(x-y).$

Comment: In the definition of $\langle \delta, h \rangle$, the integral is $h(x)$. Should it be $h(0)$? Or maybe I am missing the point?

Comment: @rainman I obmit $(x)$ to emphasize that it works on function $h$, rather than value $h(x)$ for each $x$. And the last value should be $h(0)$. I made a mistake and had corrected it.